# How to get maximum value from an array column in Snowflake?

Tags: database, data-warehouse, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-task

I have a column in snowflake table which is varchar type and contains comma(,) seperated values in it.
I used `split(mycolumn,',')` to change all the comma(,) seperated values into an array. Now, After using `split` function i have an array of values.

How can i get maximum value from this array?

I Tried both `max()` and `greatest()` functions but no use.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
    select sum(c.value::number) as val
from dual,
     lateral flatten(input=>split('1,2,33',',')) c;
```

(generally you need to flatten the array before you can SUM it)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using [LATERAL FLATTEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html)

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE TestTable (
  ID  INTEGER
 ,ColLabel  VARCHAR
 ,ColValues  VARIANT
)
AS
  SELECT $1
        ,$2
        ,PARSE_JSON($3)
    FROM VALUES
           (1, 'Jon', '[2,4,6]')
          ,(2, 'Susan', '[10]')
          ,(3, 'Sally', '[25,25,25,25]')
;
SELECT T.ID
      ,T.ColLabel
      ,SUM(F.VALUE::INTEGER) AS ColValues_Elem
  FROM TestTable AS T
      ,LATERAL FLATTEN(T.ColValues) AS F
      GROUP BY T.ID, T.ColLabel
;
```

Results:

```
ID  COLLABEL    COLVALUES_ELEM
1   Jon         12
2   Susan       10
3   Sally       100
```